# Largest closed subset of an half-open interval

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology

I have problems understanding the following:

Consider the set $A = ]0,1] \cup  \{2 \}$. What is the largest closed subset of $A$ ? I know that $X_n \subset A$ with $X_n = [1/n , 1] \cup \{2 \} $ and that $X_n \subset X_{n+1}$ for all $n \in \mathbb{N}$. I also know that $X_n$ is closed. So to get the largest closed set I have to take the limit but I also know that $\bigcup_{n \in \mathbb{N}} \ X_n = ]0,1] \cup \{2 \} $ which is not closed anymore. My question is: how can I possibly construct the largest closed set with my definition of the set $X_n$ ? Or is this not possible ?

Comment: Closed in $\mathbb R$?  or closed in $A$?  Or what?

Comment: Closed in $\mathbb{R}$.

Comment: Well, as your question is worded, "closed subset of $A$" could very easily mean "closed subset of the topological space $A$", which would be $A$ itself, in the subspace topology relative to $\mathbb R$. Every topological space is a closed subset of itself. If the intention was "Closed in $\mathbb R$" then the wording should have been "What is the largest closed subset of $\mathbb R$ contained in $A$" (in which case the answer is that it doesn't exist, as the answer below shows).

Answer (score 2):

This is not possible. Indeed, assume that $F$ is a closed subset of $A$. Then $0 \notin F$ so there exists $\varepsilon > 0$ such that $F \cap \langle -\varepsilon, \varepsilon\rangle = \emptyset$.

Then $F \cup \left\{\frac\varepsilon2\right\}$ is a closed subset of $A$ which strictly contains $F$.